# Python xml elementree how to check if element if present and process code?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml.etree

```
<rules>
    <entry name="rule name 1">
      <to>
        <member>untrust</member>
      </to>
      <from>
        <member>trust</member>
      </from>
      <source>
        <member>object1</member>
      </source>
      <destination>
        <member>any</member>
      </destination>
      <service>any</service>
      <description>'NAT Rule 1'</description>
      <nat-type>ipv4</nat-type>
      <source-translation>
        <static-ip>
          <bi-directional>yes</bi-directional>
          <translated-address>object1-pub</translated-address>
        </static-ip>
      </source-translation>
    </entry>
    <entry name="rule name 2">
      <to>
        <member>untrust</member>
      </to>
      <from>
        <member>trust</member>
      </from>
      <source>
        <member>any</member>
      </source>
      <destination>
        <member>object2-pub</member>
      </destination>
      <destination-translation>
        <translated-address>object2</translated-address>
      </destination-translation>
      <service>any</service>
      <description>'NAT Rule 2'</description>
      <tag>
        <member>DST NAT</member>
      </tag>
    </entry>
</rules>
```

Hi,

I am trying to process above xml using xml elementree in python. I am looking for a way to check if the <'source-traslation'> or <'destination-translation'> is present. In short, if it if source-translation then set nat-type varialble to source nat and proceed further to get  and <'translated-address'> values. If <'destination-address'> is present then process logic to get values for . I am putting all this data in a dict with a format like this...

```
rules{
        rule_name: <name>
        options:{
                src_zone:<from>
                source:<source>
                dst_zone:<to>
                destination:<destination>
                nat-type:<appliaction>
                service:<service>
                traslated-address:<translated-address>
                destination-address:<destination-address>
        }       
}
```

I have tried various combinations however it is not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

To check if your element exists you can have an if statement like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse('PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE').getroot()
if len(root.findall('source-translation')) > 0:
    PUT YOUR CODE HERE
```

Comment: can root find subelement which is under child or do I need to loop it through the child node. In the final configuration, i will be parsing 300+ rule entry blocks.